# Is there a fast way to find where a constraint lies in?

Tags: database

When JDBC or something alike throws an exception: `violate constraint XXX`, the `XXX` is not a meaningful name, like `FK123456789` or `PK12344556`, I want to know which table constains this contraint. Is it possible?

At the moment I am just looking among all tables one by one. It is too slow, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle then you can get all the database constraints using:

```
select * from user_constraints
```